# If user has clicked link add class and store using PHP/Wordpress

Tags: php, html, jquery, wordpress

I have multiple divs on my website that are clickable. I simply want that when the user clicks this div, a class is then added so they know they have viewed this.

For example, we could have a list of 10 links on the site. Once they click a link, the 'viewed' class would be added, to set a background colour to green.

I know the below is a simply way to do this in jQuery, but if someone could please help with storing this in PHP it would help so much, I am quite stuck on this!

```js
$(function() {
  $('.clickable-links > div').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("viewed");
  });
});
```

```css
.viewed {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="clickable-links">
  <div class="link1">Lnk 1</div>
  <div class="link2">Lnk 2</div>
  <div class="link3">Lnk 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "storing this in php". Do you want to persist that state in a Database ?

Comment: Because if the user comes back another day, I want it to show that they have already clicked a link

Comment: You cant simply "store this in php". You need some sort of persistance like a database or a cookie.

Comment: This was edited to say 'store this in php'. This is using wordpress, so I would like to know how to do this

Comment: As i mentionend above, you need to either store that state in a Database, which in case of wordpress there might be plugin for that, or you have to set a [cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774773/how-can-i-set-store-cookie-when-anchor-clicked/12774889).

Comment: This would be best served using PHP `$_SESSION` global. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117252/how-to-store-and-receive-variables-in-wp-sessions

Answer (score 0):

You could add a jquery ajax in order to save the status change in your php.
By example:

```
$(function() {
    $('.clickable-links > div').click(function() {
    link= $(this).text()
    $(this).addClass("viewed");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/url/to/php/script",
        data: "link=" + link,
        })
    })
});
```

Then in your PHP script you acces the clicked link with:

```
$link=$_POST['link']
```

It's just a thought. It can be improved.

Comment: Is there another way in Wordpress do you know?

Comment: What you need is a new feature that does not belong to the WordPress core. For that you need to create a plugin that will solve the problem. Within the Plugin you can use a method like the one I described above or some other, but the key here is that the additional functionality must be created programmatically through WordPress Plugins. 
A good place to start would be [here](https://www.wpbeaverbuilder.com/creating-wordpress-plugin-easier-think/)